# Fedora 25 on iMac firewire disk boot timeout

Tags: linux, boot, mac

I have installed Fedora 25 on a external SSD connected to my iMac Core 2 Duo. This means I have OS X on the internal HDD and Fedora 25 on the firewire connected SSD. I select the boot device using "alt" key at startup.

When I try to boot Fedora it always goes into emergency mode the first time with reason (I have cut and pasted the messages that seems most important):

```
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-fedora\x2dhome.device  
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e27f56c7\x2d7b40\... blablabla 
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3490c620\...  
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-fedora\x2dswap.device  
Failed to start udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization
```

If I reboot from emergency mode, Fedora starts up normally without error. At warm boot there is no timout.
At cold boot the issue comes back every time.

How can I troubleshoot this issue. What to look for?

BR, 
Martin

Comment: This is a system that is using a purely live USB/DVD install or net install?  Also can you share output of   'cat /etc/fstab' via a paste service

Comment: I installed Fedora using anaconda from an live usb. Here is fstab: http://pastebin.com/dXvwf61a and dmesg is here: http://pastebin.com/g2pXsj8J